# Pointer to first element of vector in Result<Vec<f64>, _> is corrupted

Tags: pointers, rust, ownership

I have a `Result<Vec<f64>, _>`. When I try to extract a pointer to the actual `f64` array, what I observe is that the array `dptr` points to is a corrupted version of the expected array (the first 10 bytes have been changed).

Why does this happen, and how I can avoid it?

```
use std::error::Error;

fn main() {
    let res: Result<Vec<f64>, Box<dyn Error>> = Ok(vec![1., 2., 3., 4.]);
    let dptr: *const f64 = match res {
        Ok(v) => &v[0], 
        Err(_) => std::ptr::null(),
    };
    assert_eq!(unsafe { *dptr }, 1.0);
}
```

Result:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `0.0`,
 right: `1.0`', src/main.rs:9:5
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a48ad66a7fa2006e52d3dd5b8dea3f0c)

Comment: I've added a [mre] and linked to a runnable version on the Rust Playground. This will make it easy for people to see what you're describing for themselves. Does this accurately capture the problem? If not, please feel free to update the code and the Playground link.

Comment: I think that does capture the gist of my problem, yes. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behaviour of that program is undefined, which can be seen by running it under Miri, which is a Rust interpreter that can sometimes detect Undefined Behavior. (you can do this in the playground by clicking "Tools" (top right) -> "Miri"):

```
error: Undefined Behavior: pointer to alloc1039 was dereferenced after this allocation got freed
 --> src/main.rs:9:25
  |
9 |     assert_eq!(unsafe { *dptr }, 1.0);
  |                         ^^^^^ pointer to alloc1039 was dereferenced after this allocation got freed
  |
  = help: this indicates a bug in the program: it performed an invalid operation, and caused Undefined Behavior
  = help: see https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html for further information
```

What's happening here is a use-after-free: the `Ok(v) => &v[0],` line moves data from `v` (and thus `res`), causing it to be freed. Later, data used for other variable overwrote the existing data (because using a pointer after the memory it points to is freed is Undefined Behaviour).

If you had tried to read the data out of the `res` the normal way without `unsafe`, you would have got a compile-time error for this very issue:

```
error[E0382]: use of partially moved value: `res`
 --> src/main.rs:9:10
  |
6 |         Ok(v) => &v[0],
  |            - value partially moved here
...
9 |     dbg!(res.unwrap()[0]);
  |          ^^^ value used here after partial move
  |
  = note: partial move occurs because value has type `Vec<f64>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
help: borrow this field in the pattern to avoid moving `res.0`
  |
6 |         Ok(ref v) => &v[0],
  |            +++
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=98965560a96feb4a429992562b254285)

Comment: If you change the match arm to grab the 3rd element, then it works alright though (`Ok(v) => &v[2]`)... What is special about index 0 or 1 that triggers the move? It still gives a Miri error, but I get the expect output (`3.0`).

Comment: @jeremymeadows The compiler doesn't clear out memory when it's freed: it just happens that there wasn't a lot of data being stored to memory between the move and the assert, so only the first two elements got overwritten with other data. But it's still Undefined Behaviour: the compiler gets to do whatever it wants in this case. If you turn on optimizations, then you *do* get an error when the 2nd element is used in the `assert`.

Comment: @jeremymeadows Some allocators fill the initial portion of the freed block with a specific pattern that makes it easier to detect corruption. Perhaps the allocator Rust uses on your system works like that.

Comment: @Smitop right, I just wouldn't have expected anything to have overwritten since we didn't use any new data, although I guess there aren't guarantees about that since it is definitely something to avoid regardless.

Comment: @user4815162342 that is super interesting, did not know that ever existed

Comment: @jeremymeadows Honestly I'm not sure that's the case here, as I'd expect the allocator to use a non-zero pattern to ease debugging - but it's the only explanation I can think of that stands up under scrutiny. Another explanation would be that the space gets reused for a different allocation that happens between the dropping of `res` and the retrieval of the vector - but such an allocation doesn't exist, and Rust doesn't insert allocations out of thin air.

Comment: @jeremymeadows A third possibility would be for the of `*dptr` to be completely optimized away by LLVM, since the memory is freed and reading it "can't happen" (is UB). But that is refuted by the fact that the issue is reproducible in debug mode, and that it happens when you [use `read_volatile()`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1e4138a1904fc305b3094742970750c0) to force the reading of the pointer content.

Comment: Actually, what I don't really understand is why dptr = &v[0] releases the data, even if only partially so. I would have expected moving a pointer not to move the data pointed to, hence no need to release its memory. What's wrong in my thinking?